# Trying to search changeset using the command tfpt searchcs in command utility gives me TF30012 error

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, tfs-power-tools

When I try searching changeset using the command `tfpt searchcs` in command utility gives me the error

> Tf30012: unable to connect to this team foundation server
>   possible reasons for failure include:
>
> - The name, port number, or protocol for the TFS is incorrect
> - The TFS is offline
> - The password has expired or incorrect
>
> Technical information (for administrator):
>
> `The remote server returned and error:(404) not found.`

I've entered the following values in the "Server Name" and "Under Server Path" fields:

- Server Name: `http://server:8080/tfs`
- Under Server Path: `$/ProjectCollectionName/ProjectName/Path/Under/Project/`

Comment: I am trying to search change sets with a keyword comment. Doing this by typing "tfpt searchcs" in command line which opens a search box for search changesets.I trying searching it gives me this error. TFS2012,powertool version 2012 is used

Comment: It just shows up Search changeset. We need to provide the server name: http://server:8080/tfs/   and under serverpath: $server\collectionname\projectname\QA when I search it gives me the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, that is what I suspected.

The values you need to enter are different than you're expecting.

You should enter

1. Not the server Uri, but the project collection uri `http://server:8080/tfs/CollectionName`
2. Not the `$/server/collection` path, but the `$/Project/path`

Akin to this:

[image: SearchCS]

If you, like me, execute the `tfpt searchcs` from a folder that is mapped to TFS, the power tools should automatically populate these fields.

Comment: I think the "Server Uri" label is from the 2005/2008 era, back then there was no such thing as a ProjectCollection. Filed a bug @Microsoft.

Comment: Now when I search I get the changeset but when I click on changeset details it opens up a box stating                                   Failed to start tf.exe. The system cannot find the file specified. Please try adding the path to tf.exe in PATH environment variable.

Comment: So are you running this from a Visual Studio Developer Command prompt or is/have you added `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE` to the path?

Comment: I am running it from the server command prompt  C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe

Comment: Then either run it from the above mentioned folder or add the folder to the path `set path=%path%;'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE'` or use a Developer Command Prompt from the Visual Studio start menu item.